# Using CTE with multiple criteria

Tags: postgresql, select, common-table-expression

I am using this code to see the unique results of **concated/joined** columns `'a,b'` from [`table1`](https://dbfiddle.uk/6bGHaO6y) and is working perfectly

```
WITH tt as ( 
SELECT concat(a,',',b) AS concated FROM table1 GROUP BY concated )
select concated  from tt;
```

But, instead of writing like `'a,b'`, I want to refer to `table2.joins` to get columns references to be **concated/joined** so that I can see together all the unique results of `table1` (based on `table2.joins`)

| line | sets | joins |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | a,b |
| 2 | 4 | a,c,f,i |
| 3 | 5 | a,d,o,x,y |
| 4 | 2 | a,e |

Tried this but getting [error.](https://dbfiddle.uk/6bGHaO6y) The expected result looks like this [(demo)](https://dbfiddle.uk/z_iBxqDO);

```
WITH tt as ( 
SELECT concat(string_to_array((select joins from table2), ',')) AS concated FROM table1 GROUP BY concated )
select concated  from tt;
```

Any simple solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please refer to this link; https://dbfiddle.uk/zm3v4tcr

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve? In your code you are mistakenly using tb_data instead of tb_reference in CTE.

Comment: @  Cetin Basoz I have improved & simplified the question, can you please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic SQL can help to solve this problem, and here you need PL/pgSQL.

```
drop table if exists concat_result;
-- create table to store a result
create table if not exists concat_result (column_header text, joins text);

do $$
declare
  -- instantiate all the necessary variables
  joins_from_table1 text[];
  joins_set text;
  current_sql text;
begin 
    
-- store all the rows as an array: {"a,b","a,c,f,i","a,d,o,x,y","a,e"}
joins_from_table1 := array(select joins from table2);

-- iterate over the array from the previous step
foreach joins_set in array joins_from_table1
loop
    -- concat_ws() helps to concat integers using a comma separator
    -- if you need unique values use DISTINCT after SELECT
    current_sql := 'insert into concat_result (column_header, joins) 
        select ''' || joins_set || ''', concat_ws('','',' || joins_set || ') from table1;';
    -- simply log the current query (optional)
    raise info '%', current_sql;
    -- run sql and insert its result to the 'concat_result' table 
    execute current_sql;
   
end loop;
end $$;
```

Comment: Tried the above, but the output is blank. can you please check the following link `https://dbfiddle.uk/zwYdSPYU`  thanks

Comment: @Gulya The result is stored in the `concat_result` table, here is the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/VZBjt20i). I've commented almost all the steps in my query, please check them out.

Comment: @ albina working perfectly thanks a lot, is there a way to add column headers also against each joins. Something like this [https://dbfiddle.uk/KN_LQS2F]

Comment: @Gulya updated my answer. **If you need unique values in the result table** use DISTINCT after SELECT (see the comments in the query).

Comment: @ albina the query is working perfectly with a small data, but if the data is around a mln then keep loading.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you are looking for :

```
WITH tt as (
  SELECT concat(unnest(string_to_array(joins, ','))) 
  AS concated 
  FROM tb_reference
  GROUP BY concated )
select concated  from tt;
```

`joins` is a column of `tb_reference`, so the `FROM` should be `FROM tb_reference`

Comment: Actually, that's not what I'm looking for. I have improved & simplified the question with my expectation, can you please check.